# running OpenJDK 11.0.1 in production

Tags: java

I manage a web application which we develop in Java, currently on JDK 8.

I am planning on migrating us up to OpenJDK 11.0.1.   We have installed this and testing has gone well :   https://jdk.java.net/11/

The download page says this is "production ready", but am I am wondering if it's generally accepted that it's safe to run OpenJDK 11 in live environments yet ?

I think what makes me nervous is that I see the Oracle commercial JDK 11 is still open for bug fixes.

Comment: No other way is currently as reliable as it could be to give it a try on your own.

Comment: 11 is an LTS release, so it will be open for bug fixes at least until the next LTS release, which is 3 years from now. But, this is a good thing, since it means that _if_ anything breaks it will probably be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source of truth is not going to be us, Oracle, or any other article(s) you can find about...but your testing. Granted all of that will rise your level of confidence, but still, it won't be.

In any case, OpenJDK (as well as Oracle SDK) `11` are production releases, also known as **LTS release**. Software is not bug-free, ever, but that is ready to be used, reused, and abused ;) ...so use it and deploy with confidence after your testing is done.